# BCP a Flat File with Veritcal Bar and Line Feed

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I am getting pretty confused trying to use BCP to update a table from a flat file and was looking for some help. I keep getting the error 
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

My command is

BCP Blank.dbo.APMAST IN F:\BItxt\apmast.txt -T -n -r\n -t"|" -L10

Am I doing this correctly I have looked all over the internet and I am just getting more confused. The table I am using to upload to is an empty table with the column names setup. The file I am pulling from is a | separated and LineFeed for end of line. Any Ideas?

Comment: Two things .. 1. Have you tried `-r\r` instead of `-r\n`.  2.  You have specified `-L10` and just want to confirm you have more than 10 lines in your file

Comment: Is there a reason you used the SSIS tag?

Comment: I was using -L10 to just test if the first 10 would work it does the same thing whether that is there or not. I have tried both \r and \n . I think the problem is the text file came straight from unix and has some garbage in it I am still working through that. Yes I included SSIS as there is also an option to do a Bulk Insert Task and I have been trying to use that which I thought was a GUI version of BCP but now looks like it is completely separate.